# How to set Response Cookie and See it on Client Site

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I need to set response cookie and return JsonResponse on server site. Basically;

```
public JsonResponse function(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //some code
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("key","value");
    cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

When I do that it does not sets the cookie. How can I do something like that.

Thanks

Comment: What is `jsonResponse`? Where does it come from?

Comment: jsonResponse is just an object I created. I already set HttpServletResponse object which is response.

Comment: are you sure you are passing the  right request, response  objects ?

Comment: yes I do pass rights ones

Comment: if jsonResponse is a HttpServletResponse  Object then you have to set `jsonResponse=response` and then return it. Thats objious , isnt it? As you have written the code, you dont assign the response with the cookie to the returned response...

Comment: no it is not. It is just an object I created. I think it is not important. It could be a String or an Integer.

Comment: but you are adding a cookie on a local object and then you dont return that object. How is it going to propagate to the user's browser?

Comment: please post all your relevant code including the doPost/doGet methods to avoid missunderstandings

Comment: a post request comes to server. it calls a function like I shared. the function who cares post request returns the result of the function I shared